# How to read data from buffer selectively

Tags: c++, c

I have an 720x576 picture saved row by row in an `unsigned char luma[414720]` and I need to display a centered picture  with size 640x480.

My question is:
What is the most efficient way to selectively access to the data saved in one buffer using just one for cycle?

Thanks for your answers.

Petr Duga

Comment: What do you mean by "just one for cycle"?

Comment: Maybe he means 'a single `for` loop'.

Comment: yes, I thought one for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

newLuma is the new pic to be displayed.

```
int i= 0;
char newLuma[640*480];
int rowStart = (576 - 480)/2 -1 ;
int colStart = (720 - 640)/2 -1 ;


for ( i = 0; i < 480; i++)
{
    memcpy(newLuma[i*640], luma[720*(rowStart + i) + colStart], 640);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jerry_Y, this is exactly what I needed. Petr Duga

Comment: Shouldn't it be `memcpy(newLuma[i*480], luma[576*(R+i)+C], 480)` where `R = (720-640)/2 - 1, C = (576-480)/2 -1`? What am I missing?

Comment: @ajay do you mean for(i = 0; i < 640; i++) with your code?

Comment: @ajay maybe the difference is 640*480 or 480*640 : ）

Comment: @Jerry_Y yes `(i = 0; i < 640; i++)`. :)

Comment: @ajay then it would be 480*640 pic in my thought.

Comment: @Jerry_Y but doesn't 640x480 mean copy the middle 480 bytes from the successive 640 rows of luma starting at row number 39?

Comment: @ajay In my opinion, 640*480 usually means width*hight， you can imagine desktop Display Resolution(640*480)， and the `width=column_count=640`, `hight=row_count=480`

Comment: @Jerry_Y yes you are right. By 640x480 I thought of it as an array of type `int[640][480]` :) Now it makes sense. Thank you :)